Trouble with Systemd and Access Denied in Windows Subsystem for Linux (WSL)
I've been encountering some issues with my Windows Subsystem for Linux (WSL) setup, particularly related to systemd and access denied errors. Here's a breakdown of the problems I've been facing:
Systemd Error:
When attempting to interact with systemd services or perform certain system-related tasks, I receive an error indicating that the system hasn't been booted with systemd as the init system (PID 1). As a result, I'm unable to operate certain functions that rely on systemd.
Access Denied Error:
I've also been experiencing "access denied" errors in various contexts, such as when attempting to restart services like snapd or dbus.service. These errors seem to prevent me from making certain system-level changes or accessing specific resources and I can't login to snap ubuntu one login details.
I've tried various troubleshooting steps, including reinstalling WSL, updating packages,adding [boot]systemd=true to wsl.conf file and checking system configurations. However, I haven't been able to resolve these issues so far.
Any insights or suggestions on how to troubleshoot and resolve these problems would be greatly appreciated.
NOTE: I'm totally new to all of this

You've tagged your release as being Ubuntu 14.04 LTS (which is years beyond being fully-supported; and didn't use systemd anyway!)  It's also too old a release that to be supported by WSL (windows subsystem isn't that old!).  Why use that tag?

@guiverc this site auto-recommends that tag for a lot of questions ( I guess since there's a lot of questions tagged with it?) and this user must have just clicked whatever was recommended to them. As of now I don't know of any way to prevent that suggestion.

to confirm: you're running Windows 11 with a WSL version that supports systemd?

@Esther Yeah I'm running window 11 and I'm quite the WSL version supports systemd too
